# Mixtures and Percentages

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Found this in Lang's "Baisc Mathematics" book:

A solution contains 35% alcohol and 65% water. If you start with 12 kg of solution, how much water must be added to make the percentage of alcohol equal to 20%?

Could someone please help me out with it?

Comment: What is $35$% of $12$kg?

Comment: @abiessu Shouldn't that be a new question?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty: it is intended as a prompt to get the OP thinking about ways to get the answer...

Comment: 4.2.

I tried .35*12+x=0.2, which solves for x = 4. However, the given answer is 9kg.

Comment: So in order to have $20$% in the final product, we need a total of $4.2\cdot 5=21$kg.  What is the next step?

Comment: Could you please clarify on how you got 5 there?

Comment: If $4.2$kg is $20$%$=\frac 15$ of the total, then the total amount is $5$ times this amount.

Comment: Thanks very much! I understand the solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the amount in kilograms of water to be added to the solution. After adding $x$ kilograms, there are $0.65\cdot 12+x=7.8+x$ kilograms of water in the solution and a total of $12+x$ kilograms of liquid making up the solution. In the end, we want the solution to be $80$% water, so we solve the following:

$$
\frac{7.8+x}{12+x}=0.8\implies x= 9.
$$